# Bijection from union of two finite, disjoint sets A, B to {1,2,...,|A| + |B|}

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

A and B are disjoint, finite sets. The goal is to prove that $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|$ using a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $\{1,2,...,|A|+|B|\}$.

Its easy to begin with:
let $x \in A\cup B$. However trying to determine a function that takes any value in $A$ or $B$ and outputs ordered natural numbers is proving difficult. My first attempt at the function gave me

$f(x) = \begin{array}{ll}
      x & x \in A \\
      x+|A| & x\in B\\
\end{array} $

But this clearly doesn't yield $\{1,2,3,...,|A|+|B|\}$, but $\{x_{a_1},x_{a_2},x_{a_3},...,x_{a_n},x_{b_1}+|A|,..., x_{b_m}+|A|\} $

Ideally I would just use:

$f(x) = \begin{array}{ll}
      i & x \in A \\
      i+|A| & x\in B\\
\end{array} $

where $i$ is the index location of $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, but I cannot find an example of a similar notation that could apply to any arbitrary finite set.

Comment: Hint: you also know there are bijections, say $g_A$ and $g_B$, from $A$ to $\{1,\dots,|A|\}$ and from $B$ to $\{1,\dots,|B|\}$, respectively. Perhaps you should incorporate those two functions into your definition of $f$, which is otherwise very much on the right track.